# Emit one observable only while other is emitting some values

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive

I'm writing sort of monitoring tool which monitors specified remote machine.
It would retrieve whether the machine is up, whether IIS is running there and some more parameters.
Machine up/down state can be monitored every let's say 3 mins.
And IIS state can be monitored every ~1 min.
If some of these parameters changed it will log the change (`DistinctUntilChanged`), if it stays the same it won't do anything.

I created one observable for machine state and one for IIS status.
Obviously there is no need to monitor any other remote parameters if machine is down (no need to call `GetIisState`).
So, I've tried to use `SkipUntil` and `TakeUntil` – trying to sort of pause `IisObservable` while machine is down.
But it doesn't work as I would want it to.

Here is my machine state observable:

```
machineStateObservable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180))
    .StartWith(-1)
    .Select(async it => new {Order = it, State = await GetMachineStateAsync(machine)})
    .Switch()
    .Do(it =>
    {
        if (it.Order == -1) // write initial state 1st time
        {
            var state = it.State ? "up" : "down";
            var msg = $"{machine.Name}: Machine initial state: {state}";
            Log.Info(msg);
        }
    })
    .Select(it => it.State);

machineStateObservable
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Buffer(2, 1).Where(it => it.Count == 2)
    .Subscribe(it => Log.Info($"{machine.Name}: MachineState got changed from {it[0]} to: {it[1]}")
        , ex => Log.Error(ex, "Unhandled exception!"));
```

How should I define `IisObservable` that it will not emit notifications (and consequently will not call `GetIisState`) while `machineStateObservable` is indicating that machine is down?

**Update:**
Here is solution which I came to with help of @Enigmativity:

```
IisStateObservable = MachineStateObservable
                .Select(state => state
                    ? Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).StartWith(0)
                                .SelectMany(it => Readings.GetServiceStateAsync())
                    : Observable.Never<string>())
                .Switch()
                .Publish();
```

Comment: Where is the call to `GetIisState`?

Comment: It's async method to return IIS state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic pattern for creating an observable that only emits when another observable produces `true` and not when it produces `false`.

```
void Main()
{
    var states = new Subject<bool>();

    IObservable<int> query =
        states
            .Select(state => state
                ? Observable.FromAsync(() => GetStatusAsync())
                : Observable.Never<int>())
            .Switch();
}

public async Task<int> GetStatusAsync()
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 42);
}
```

---

Here's the code I'd suggest that is called periodically.

```
void Main()
{
    var states = new Subject<bool>();

    IObservable<int> query =
    (
        from n in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0))
        from ms in Observable.FromAsync(() => GetMachineStateAsync())
        select ms
            ? Observable.FromAsync(() => GetStatusAsync())
            : Observable.Never<int>()
    ).Switch();
}

public async Task<int> GetStatusAsync()
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 42);
}

public async Task<bool> GetMachineStateAsync()
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => true);
}
```

---

Or, alternatively, based on your suggested answer.

```
void Main()
{
    var states = new Subject<bool>();

    IObservable<int> query =
        states
            .Select(state => state
                ? Observable
                    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
                    .StartWith(-1L)
                    .SelectMany(n =>
                        Observable.FromAsync(() => GetStatusAsync()))
                : Observable.Never<int>())
            .Switch();
}

public async Task<int> GetStatusAsync()
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 42);
}
```

Comment: This is nice code and I'll use it.
However when machine is up I need to call GetStatusAsync and continue to call it every say 1min, not once.

Comment: @IgorStack - Yes, that's easy - start the whole thing with an `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0))`, but you're then likely to call a `GetStateAsync` to get your state value.

Comment: @IgorStack - I had a look at your answer. I'd use `.SelectMany` rather than `.Select(...)`/`.Switch()` - you do risk not getting any values with the switch approach.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last comment? (pretty new to Rx).

Comment: @IgorStack - If the call to `Readings.GetServiceStateAsync()` takes longer than 2 seconds then a new `Interval` value is produced and then the `.Switch()` will drop the value from the previous call. If that happens ongoingly then you never get any values.